# no member named 'log2' in namespace 'std'

Tags: c++, clang

Why I have an error in clang 14 for `rv32gc` but not for the `x86-64` toolchain?

```
no member named 'log2' in namespace 'std'
```

Compilation example: https://godbolt.org/z/a7hfzGP34

According to the standard, it should be available since C++11: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2 . Why the architecture matter? Surprisingly, without the `std::` prefix it works.

Comment: Different CPUs have different instruction sets.  I can see this being a compiler intrinsic that just wasn't added to the RISC version of the clangs standard library.  Without `std::` you get the C version of the function which may be different.

Comment: do  ``` log2(10);```  instead of ```std:: log2(10);``` log2() is a cmath function not std.

Comment: @Jocefyneroot All `<cname>` headers put there functions in `std` unless they are a macro.

Comment: there are also lot of logics behind it if you explore then you got the idea but try to removing std

Comment: You are right. The definition should be there. I see no language in the standard that makes that function optional or gives it a feature test macro. That's simply a flaw in the toolchain, as far as I can tell